# OnClick ChangeImage And URL

Tags: javascript, html

I have the main image and a zoom icon for it and I have an image next to the first image. I wanna write a JavaScript code where when I click on the second image it changes the first image `scr` and the zoom icon's `href` link I found a code for it, but I can't make it work. This is the code I have so far:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function change(menuId, image, newImage, newUrl)
{
    var img = document.getElementById(image);
    img.src = newImage;
    document.getElementById('d3').href = newUrl;
} 
</script>
```

and i tried to do make it work like that

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function change(menuId, image, newImage, newUrl)
{
    var img = document.getElementById(image);
    img.src = newImage;
    document.getElementById('d3').href = newUrl;
} 
</script>
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <div id="main_img">
             <img id="img" src="assets/example/latest/S8621A.png" alt=""/>
            <div class="caption">
                <span class="ico-block">
                    <a class="ico-zoom" href="assets/example/latest/S8621A.png" id="d3"><span></span></a>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
            </div>
        <div style="text-align:center">
<div id="thumb_img">
    <img src='assets/img/fekete.png' onclick='changeImage("assets/example/latest/S8621A.png")' >
    <img src='assets/img/barna.png' onclick='changeImage("assets/example/latest/S8621B.png")' onclick='document.getElementById'("d3").href = '(assets/example/latest/S8621B.png)'>
</div></div>
```

I just don't know how it should work. I really don't understand that whole JavaScript. Can someone help me or show me how will it work? THX for the help.

Comment: Wehre do you call `change()` and what does the method `changeImage()`do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- As others have already said, `change()` should be `changeImage()` or vice versa.
- There was no obvious target for the `MenuId` parameter so it's removed.
- Made the `zoomImage()` function just for the hell of it.
- Click any of the bottom images and the top one changes and the `GO` link's `href` changes as well.
- The zoom icon will enlarge the top image by 50% without leaving the page.
- Added 2 more functions…not sure what OP wants.

  - `imageZoom()` will use `transform: scale()` to zoom the image.
  - `resetImage()` will reset the image back to 128px

**Snippet**

```css
img {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function changeImage(newImage, newUrl) {
    var img = document.getElementById('img');
    img.src = newImage;
    document.getElementById('goto').href = newUrl;
    return false;
  }

  function zoomImage() {
    var img = document.getElementById('img');
    if (img.style.width == "192px") {
      img.style.width = "128px"
    } else {
      img.style.width = "192px";
    }
    return false;
  }

  function imageZoom() {
    var img = document.getElementById('img');
    if (img.style.width == "512px") {
      img.style.transform = "scale(.25)";
    } else {
      img.style.transform = "scale(4)";
    }
    return false;;
  }

  function resetImage() {
    var img = document.getElementById('img');
      img.style.width = "0px";
      img.style.transform = "scale(1)"
      img.style.width = "128px";
      return false;
    }

</script>
<div class="thumbnail">

  <div id="main_img">
    <img id="img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png" alt="" width="128" />
    <div class="caption">

      <div class="ico-block">
        <a id="goto" href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png">GO</a>
        <a class="ico-big" href="#" id="d3" width="32" onclick="zoomImage();">
          <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/rafiqul-hassan/blogger/32/Zoom-In-icon.png" />
        </a>
        <a class="ico-zoom" href="#" id="3d" width="32" onclick="imageZoom();">
          <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/zoom-in-pc_318-11477.jpg" width="32" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="text-align:center">
  <div id="thumb_img">
    <img src='http://i44.tinypic.com/2uxz43b.jpg' onclick='changeImage("http://cnx.org/resources/b785d2ec9b6302264f1ed942f4ec1b822d6f7b4c/lena.jpg", "http://cnx.org/resources/b785d2ec9b6302264f1ed942f4ec1b822d6f7b4c/lena.jpg")' width="128">
    <img src='http://www.log85.com/tmp/doc/img/perfectas/lenna/lenna1.jpg' onclick='changeImage("http://lh3.ggpht.com/_ERXQs5oLNgE/S01Ee_26lsI/AAAAAAAAAlY/1T0Dl4QJiYk/s800/lenaV.jpg", "http://lh3.ggpht.com/_ERXQs5oLNgE/S01Ee_26lsI/AAAAAAAAAlY/1T0Dl4QJiYk/s800/lenaV.jpg")'
    width="128">
    <button onclick="resetImage();">RESET</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i don't understand that i can't make it work for the ico-zoom to zoom on the picture. I'm only using html and doesn't put anything into .js files or anything.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying...did the demo work the way you wanted it to? Did you try to integrate the demo into your own project?

Comment: Added another zoom function and a reset function.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```js
function changeImage(element,newUrl) {
      element.src = newUrl;
      document.getElementById('d3').href = newUrl;
    }
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail">
  <div id="main_img">
    <img id="img" src="assets/example/latest/S8621A.png" alt="" />
    <div class="caption">
      <span class="ico-block">
                    <a class="ico-zoom" href="assets/example/latest/S8621A.png" id="d3"><span></span>
      </a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="text-align:center">
  <div id="thumb_img">
    <img src='assets/img/fekete.png' onclick='changeImage(this, "assets/example/latest/S8621A.png")'>
    <img src='assets/img/barna.png' onclick='changeImage(this, "assets/example/latest/S8621B.png")' onclick='document.getElementById' ( "d3").href='(assets/example/latest/S8621B.png)'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it still doesn't work for me i posted my updated code in the comments can you tell me what i did wrong?

Comment: Have you replaced the onclick parameter value and the changeImage function as provided in my answer? I tested the code and the src of the image will be replaced by the url provided in the function call.

Comment: yeah it changes the image. that part is working. But i want it to change the "href" of the ico-zoom as well, and that part doesn't work unfortunately:(

Comment: I've added a new Line to the JS Snippet. It will change the href of the ico-zoom.

Comment: Now when i click on the image it changes the main image to a question mark(like no image found) and the ico-zoom's url doesn't change.:( I posted my new full html part for it in the comments.

Comment: No Javascript Code provided.

Comment: i only use this javascript in the HTML. what i posted.

Comment: Please try to use the code provided in my comment. You'll need the Javascript code. And please remove the second onclick parameter on the img tag.

Comment: I tried it and it changes the photo to a question mark and the other href doesn't update. I only placed it into the index.html i don't know what else should i do. It doesn't work that way.:( Updated the code in my comment)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make sure the js function works.
Second, `<img src='assets/img/barna.png' onclick='changeImage("assets/example/latest/S8621B.png")' onclick='document.getElementById'("d3").href = '(assets/example/latest/S8621B.png)'>` is not right, it should be 
`<img src='assets/img/barna.png' onclick='changeImage("assets/example/latest/S8621B.png")' onclick='document.getElementById("d3").href = "assets/example/latest/S8621B.png"'>` if my understanding is right.

Comment: i want the img/barna.png when i click on it to change the main image "scr" and the ico-zoom's "href" and it still doesn't work with your correction:(

Answer (score 0):

Small description would be: you just need to assign clicked image to zoom icon to give it toggle effect.[that we doing by `getElementById("d3")` part

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

function changeImage(element,newUrl) {
      element.src = newUrl;
      document.getElementById("d3").href= newUrl;
    }
    </script>
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div id="main_img">
                 <img id="img" src="assets/example/latest/S8621A.png" alt=""/>
                <div class="caption">
                    <span class="ico-block">
                        <a class="ico-zoom" href="assets/example/latest/S8621A.png" id="d3"><span></span></a>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
                </div>
            <div style="text-align:center">
    <div id="thumb_img">
        <img src='assets/img/fekete.png' onclick='changeImage(this, "assets/example/latest/S8621A.png")'>
    <img src='assets/img/barna.png' onclick='changeImage(this, "assets/example/latest/S8621B.png")'>
  </div>
    </div></div>
```

Comment: i don't understand it what should i do where you wrote "this"?

Comment: You dont have to write anything at place of "this". "this" is a keyword which gives reference to current element

so when you click on barna.png image, "this" will refer to that image element

Comment: okay but that way when i click on the "barna.png" it changes the image to a question mark. and doesn't update the ico-zoom's href:(

Answer (score 0):

Hey Robert Updated now

```html
<!-- start: Portfolio -->
<section id="portfolio-grid" class="portfolio">

    <article class="javascript html">
<script type="text/javascript">
      function changeImage(element,newUrl) {
      element.src = newUrl;
      document.getElementById('d3').href = newUrl;
    }
        </script>
<div class="thumbnail">
  <div id="main_img">
    <img id="img" src="assets/example/latest/S8621A.png" alt="" />
    <div class="caption">
      <span class="ico-block">
                    <a class="ico-zoom" href="assets/example/latest/S8621A.png" id="d3"><span></span>
      </a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="text-align:center">
  <div id="thumb_img">
    <img src='assets/img/fekete.png' onclick='changeImage(this, "assets/example/latest/S8621A.png")'>
    <img src='assets/img/barna.png' onclick='changeImage(this, "assets/example/latest/S8621B.png")'>
  </div>
</div>
```